# Can a jailbroken iPhone 3GS be safely upgraded to the latest iOS via iTunes?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

If someone has an unlocked, jailbroken phone, what will happen if the update button is clicked in iTunes? Will the phone be updated and work? My friend wants to do that.

I did the same a month ago when my friend gave me the iPhone and everything worked well. His phone was also unlocked and jailbroken, but, after the update, I wasn't required to do any of the stuff. My phone is working well and I am able to download and purchase apps from the App Store.

Should I proceed with updating my friend's phone too?

Comment: unlocking and jailbreaking may not go hand in hand.. an officially unlocked phone may also be jailbroken. please check if your friend is currently using ultrasn0w to unlock.. it will be there in the cydia app in the iphone. in case ultrasn0w is there it means its illegally unlocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for it! You'll lose the jail break (duh!) but it'll restore to a normal state like any other iPhone.

Comment: Thanks mate. My friend doesn't have any idea about the jailbreak. Neither she uses it to install apps from other sources. All, I was concerned about, was the unlocking of the phone. Now that you have given the nod, I will proceed further. Once again thanks

Comment: The phone will be locked again, though!

Comment: huh !! really ?? will the phone be locked again ??. I did this to my iphone but it wasn't locked. Just that it was a normal os and not jailbroken

Comment: Unlocking is part of the jail break (unless done officially through your carrier)